# Converting Excel to Gsheet and then importrange them without needing Auth

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I receive files in .xlsx which is updated about daily.  To use the `importrange` function I need to have the xlsx file converted to gSheet. I've completed the conversion as per drive API

```
function importXLS(){
  var folderBId = "redacted"; // This is the folder where we will save the gsheet converted files

  fileID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("DataFile").getValue();


  var xFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var name = xFile.getName();
  if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')>-1){ 
    var ID = xFile.getId();
    var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
    var newFile = {
      title : name+'_converted',
      parents: [{id: folderBId}] //  Added
    };
    file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
      convert: true
    });
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("GDatafile").setValue(file.id); // **Notes below**
    // Drive.Files.remove(ID); // Added // If this line is run, the original XLSX file is removed. So please be careful this.
  }
```

So I save the new gSheet ID in my spreadsheet so I can use `importrange` to import it. But because it's a new gsheet file for every update, and not an overwritten version of the old one, I need to explicitly give access to the file.  The point here is to automate, and having to click "allow" for every time you access it is not ideal.

Can I somehow (since I have the fileID at my disposal here anyway, and the spreadsheet that will want to access it) allow access right there? Or is there a way that I can set up this 'converting' code to overwrite the old gsheet (so that I only have to allow access once).

Comment: Why not read and import the data directly with your code?

Comment: so I did when the extracts were in .csv format, but in .xlsx I (think I) have to convert it so I can just use =importrange to bring it in.  But I believe i've sorted it out. Will be posting solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
function importXLS(){
  var folderBId = "redacted"; // This is the folder where we will save the gsheet converted files

  fileID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("DataFile").getValue();


  var xFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var name = xFile.getName();
 

  if (name.indexOf('.xlsx')>-1){ 
    var ID = xFile.getId();
    var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
    var newFile = {
      title : name+'_gsheet',
      parents: [{id: folderBId}]
    };
    var GDataFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("GDatafile").getValue();

    if (GDataFile == "" ){
      file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
        convert: true
      })
      Logger.log("New File Created: " + file.id);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("GDatafile").setValue(file.id);
    }
    else{
      file = Drive.Files.update(newFile,GDataFile,xBlob); // <--- this is the update code
      Logger.log("File in theory updated... " + GDataFile);  
    }   
    // Drive.Files.remove(ID); // Added // If this line is run, the original XLSX file is removed. So please be careful this.
  }

}
```